# I have repeatedly defined animation in this code. Is not there a simpler way to do this?

Tags: android, animation

I have repeatedly defined animation in this code. Is not there a simpler way to do this? the code works the way I want it, but I want to simplify my encoding.can you help me. How should I follow a method. [How to add wait time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210171/how-to-add-wait-time/51210724#51210724)
I made a code that I could not do in this title but it came to be written much shorter

```
resimyukle();

            hediye=getDrawable(R.drawable.hediye);
            final ImageView[] imajlar={img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8};

                  Animation fadein=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  imajlar[0].setBackground(hediye);
                  imajlar[0].startAnimation(fadein);

                  Animation res=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res4=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res5=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
                  Animation res6=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);


                  anima(fadein,res,imajlar[1]);
                  anima(res,res1,imajlar[2]);
                  anima(res1,res2,imajlar[3]);
                  anima(res2,res3,imajlar[4]);
                  anima(res3,res4,imajlar[5]);
                  anima(res4,res5,imajlar[6]);
                  anima(res5,res6,imajlar[7]);
}


public void anima(final Animation aa, final Animation bb, final ImageView img)
{


    aa.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            animation.cancel();
            img.setBackground(hediye);
            img.startAnimation(bb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: the animations look the same. just create a method that does the code and call that method when you need it.

Comment: I know it but when I do it all starts and ends at the same time

Comment: so then u may need a few methods. one method does the animation, another does the waiting. the method that waits, can take in a long and then u can dynamically change the how it waits...

Comment: Remember the DRY principle. Look for things that are the same, and factor out the parts that chage.

Comment: The main problem is that when I call the animation object again after I use it, it repeats the previous animation. I have not solved this problem. Do not you think the room is absurd again?The main problem is that when I call the animation object again after I use it, it repeats the previous animation. I have not solved this problem. Do not you think the room is absurd again?

Answer (score 0):

```
hediye=getDrawable(R.drawable.hediye);
final ImageView[] imajlar={img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8};
Animation res=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fadein);
for (int i = 0; i < imajlar.size; i++) {
  anima(res, imajlar[i], i);
}
```

And your method:

```
public void anima(Animation aa, ImageView img, int id)
{
    aa.setStartOffset(id * 500);
    aa.setDuration(1000);
    img.startAnimation(aa);
    img.setBackground(hediye);
}
```

Comment: The animation of all of them played together. idont want this. i'm working for him :-(

Comment: Thats why i added `aa.setStartOffset(id * 500);`. Did you try this?

Comment: same The animation object of all of them played together. idont want this. i'm working for him :-(